# Crash with "Out of Virtual Memory"

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management

I'm maintaining an existing application and I've encountered a bug when running under some conditions (easily reproducible), where the app fails with message :

- Title: "Windows - Out of virtual memory"
- Content: "Windows is low in virtual memory..."

Question is: what I need to check first? When is this message happening? Why?

What is stored in this virtual memory in C#, why an out of memory?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like you have a memory or resource leak of some kind. Time to crack open a profiler and see what's consuming resources or memory.

Good profilers include

http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler

and

http://memprofiler.com/

-- this will attach to your running process and see what's out of control.

In general this kind of issue can be caused by objects that implement `IDisposable` not being disposed through a call to `Dispose()`. The memory and resources used by these objects are not managed by the .NET garbage collector so (unlike regular .NET objects) they won't be tidied up by the system automatically.

A profiler will usually tell you if this is an issue.

There are other situations where this can happen, for instance

- Allocation of very large blocks of memory, e.g. 40Gb arrays
- Very heavily loaded systems that don't have a chance to properly garbage collect can exceed their virtual memory allocation.

Again, a profiler will tell you where the problem is likely to lie.

Comment: Seems to be the only solution, use a profiler. Thanks for the links

Comment: Most profilers have a 30-day free trial... which can be useful!

Answer (score 2):

Windows uses [Virtual Memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) for memory management, but the memory being virtual isn't the issue here. What this indicates is that your application allocates a lot of memory - more than available on the system.

Some things that might cause this:

- You are using unmanaged code somewhere that fails to release memory.
- You allocate enormous blocks of data (e.g. dynamic calculation of an array size that incorrectly allocates 2GB of data).
- You keep references to buffers around longer than needed which prevents the garbage collector from reclaiming the memory.

Without knowing more about your application it is impossible to give any more detailed hints.

Comment: I'm new to the app' and have no more informations to provide at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you're application is taking a lot of memory. You can read about virtual memory here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2008/11/17/3155406.aspx